# Ajax response with french encoding

Tags: ajax, encoding

Is it possible to make json response with characters in french encoding? IE6 never invoke callback function to handle json response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Otherwise a lot of site wouldn't work! :)

Just make sure the server send the data back in UTF-8 encoding.

For example in java it's:

```
response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same jquery ajax request but with spring mvc and oracle.
For me this line worked: (In-case if above solution does not work for anyone.)

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
```