# PHP replaces anything that has a non-english character with null when pulling data from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I pull markers' data from a *MYSQL* database using *SQL* and build up an array of markers(with attributes **location**, **name**, **address**, **phone_number**).

At the end of the script I `echo json_encode($myarray)`.

For some reason, if say, **name** or **address** of a particular marker ends up having any French symbol(e.g. é) - PHP just replaces the entire name or address with `null`. Meanwhile my database tables are handling French symbols fine.

What gives?

Comment: encoding issues : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583983/ajax-response-with-french-encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem with Hindi content. For me, what solved it was setting the charset to UTF-8 before the data pull. I refer you to this page on how to do that.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php